# How to listen to UITextField text change event in Nativescript?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I want to listen to the text change event of a Nativescript TextView element on iOS. I think the native element that corresponds to TextView element is UITextField in iOS. How can I listen to this event in Nativescript?

I found code examples in Swift but I cannot understand Swift syntax. A code example in Nativescript would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/text-view and here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#event-binding, you can do it like this:

```
<TextView textChange="onTextChange" >
</TextView>
```

then in JS:

```
function onTextChange(args) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

There is nothing iOS specific, this should work on both platforms.

Comment: **Note:** The above syntax only works with v6.x and later. Earlier versions do not support `textChange` event from XML. You will have to add the listener programatically upon loaded event of the textfield.

Comment: But what is `args`? Where can I see what properties it has?